# Element API - remove response limit

Tags: plugin-elementapi

Using Element API I would like to remove the limit to how many entries are in the JSON output.

The default is 100 entries, with pagination. I would like 1 response with all entries.

Here is my current call:

```
return [
'endpoints' => [
    'fullmembers.json' => [
        'elementType' => 'User',
        'criteria' => ['group' => 'fullMembership'],
        'transformer' => function(UserModel $member) {
//....
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set the criteria model's `limit` parameter to null and [disable pagination](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ElementAPI#paginate).

```
'criteria' => [
    'group' => 'fullMembership',
    'limit' => null,
],
'paginate' => false,
```

Comment: Thanks Carlcs, but that still results in this: {"pagination":{"total":409,"count":100,"per_page":100,"current_page":1,"total_pages":5,"links":{"next":"http:\/\/craft.fira\/fullmembers.json?page=2"}}}}

Comment: Oh, you have to disable pagination. Will update the answer.